# Predictions in a control loop like airconditions

Tags: endogeneity, linear-dynamical-system

I wonder if there are special things to consider with predictions in a control loop, e.g.

An airconditioner trys to hold the target temperature at 20 degrees. I want to predict the energy consumption, which should depend on the target temperature negatively and on the ambient temperature positively.

When the target ambient temp increases the room temperature increases and so will the target temperature for a short time. The energy consumption will increase as well. On the other hand the energy would decrease when I increase the target temp.

What would be a good data based approach to predict the energy saving with a target temp of 22 instead of 20 degrees?